# Having trouble with iPad Mini memory issues

Tags: memory, crash, sprite-kit

I am working on a game that runs fine on new devices, but has constant crashes on the original iPad Mini, and it seems to just be insufficient memory issues. Since the original iPad Mini has (I believe) half the RAM of newer iPads, I'm sort of surprised that this doesn't come up more often.

How do big, more complex games do it, is it a normal thing to detect whether the user is using an iPad Mini and then send it less animations perhaps? One of my problems is that I'm using Sprite Kit, and I can't control when it releases the memory used by unused sprites. I was told by an Apple engineer that in order to have them release every time, I need to load them using **spriteUsingImage**: instead of **spriteUsingImageNamed**:, but even when I switched to that, they didn't seem to be releasing the memory they use.

Comment: Can you show your code where you remove sprites etc? And have you used Instruments to track memory usage - this may show other areas you can save memory e.g. do you have background nodes that could be using up too much memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory issues are occurring because of sprite usage, you should implement Sprite Pooling. Which means you create a pool of sprites that you recycle instead of constantly creating and removing them.